# ITextsharp dll files are redistributed files?

Tags: c#, dll, itext

I am complete new to Redistributed word. What is redistributed means? and iTextsharp dll files are redistributed files? Please help me.

Comment: Check the license file.

Comment: Flagged as off topic because it's not a question about programming but about licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you've found the word "redistributed". I just returned from the [Open Source India (OSI) Days](http://osidays.com/osidays/) in Bangalore where I've presented the following topics:

- [Open source: an introduction to IP and Legal](http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/open-source-an-introduction-to-ip-and-legal)
- [How can large open source projects be monitized](http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/how-can-large-open-source-projects-be-monetized)

You can also watch this 1-minute video: [iText License - Is iText Free?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHF3xcWnSD4)

Summarized:

- You can distribute the iTextSharp DLLs for free, on condition that you distribute them along with the iTextSharp source code **and your own source code** for free. All code needs to be released under the AGPL. This means that your source code needs to be Free / Open Source Software too.
- The moment you don't want to redistribute your own source code, you can not use iTextSharp for free anymore. In that case, you need to purchase a commercial license.
- As defined by the AGPL, distribution also includes using iTextSharp in the context of Software as a Service (SaaS).
- The term modification is to be interpreted in a very broad sense. Linking to AGPL software is already considered as modification.

As you can see in the first slide deck presented at the OSI Days, iText has done an IP review and can prove that all IP related to iText(Sharp) is owned by iText Group. Hence iText Group can release iText(Sharp) under whichever license it chooses to. Currently, the software is released under the AGPL as well as under a commercial license. Certain add-ons are only available under a closed source, proprietary license.

As you can see in the second slide deck, the open source license can be enforced.